# Is custom navigation drawer possible?

Tags: dart, flutter

[image]

is it possible to make custom navigation drawer like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Persistent drawers are not implemented yet in flutter.

On the other hand, simple drawers exists,
You can open them like: `Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer()`.

Comment: can reply my tooltip question ?